# Errors about using buffer in VHDL project

Tags: vhdl, xilinx-ise

I am a beginner to VHDL. I am trying to implement a simple project but I got some errors. The first one is about using buffers.

This is my entity code:

```
entity Demultiplexer is
Port ( A : in  STD_LOGIC;
       S : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
       I0 : out  STD_LOGIC;
       I1 : out  STD_LOGIC;
       I2 : out  STD_LOGIC;
       I3 : out  STD_LOGIC;
       I4 : out  STD_LOGIC;
       I5 : out  STD_LOGIC;
       I6 : out  STD_LOGIC;
       I7 : out  STD_LOGIC);
end Demultiplexer;
```

and this is my architecture:

```
architecture Behavioral of Demultiplexer is
begin
    I0 <= A WHEN S = "000" ELSE
    I1 <= A WHEN S = "001" ELSE
    I2 <= A WHEN S = "010" ELSE
    I3 <= A WHEN S = "011" ELSE
    I4 <= A WHEN S = "100" ELSE
    I5 <= A WHEN S = "101" ELSE
    I6 <= A WHEN S = "110" ELSE
    I7 <= A WHEN S = "111";
end Behavioral;
```

This the error list

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:288 - "H:\SetUpSoftwares\XilinxProjects\Assignments- 1\Demultiplexer.vhd" Line 49: Cannot read from 'out' object i1 ; use   'buffer' or 'inout'
ERROR:HDLCompiler:1731 - "H:\SetUpSoftwares\XilinxProjects\Assignments-1\Demultiplexer.vhd" Line 49: found '0' definitions of operator "<=", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "<="
ERROR:HDLCompiler:288 - "H:\SetUpSoftwares\XilinxProjects\Assignments-1\Demultiplexer.vhd" Line 50: Cannot read from 'out' object i2 ; use 'buffer' or 'inout'
ERROR:HDLCompiler:1731 - "H:\SetUpSoftwares\XilinxProjects\Assignments-1\Demultiplexer.vhd" Line 50: found '0' definitions of operator "<=", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "<="
ERROR:HDLCompiler:288 - "H:\SetUpSoftwares\XilinxProjects\Assignments-1\Demultiplexer.vhd" Line 51: Cannot read from 'out' object i3 ; use 'buffer' or 'inout'
ERROR:HDLCompiler:1731 - "H:\SetUpSoftwares\XilinxProjects\Assignments-1\Demultiplexer.vhd" Line 51: found '0' definitions of operator "<=", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "<="
ERROR:HDLCompiler:288 - "H:\SetUpSoftwares\XilinxProjects\Assignments-1\Demultiplexer.vhd" Line 52: Cannot read from 'out' object i4 ; use 'buffer' or 'inout'
ERROR:HDLCompiler:1731 - "H:\SetUpSoftwares\XilinxProjects\Assignments-1\Demultiplexer.vhd" Line 52: found '0' definitions of operator "<=", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "<="
ERROR:HDLCompiler:288 - "H:\SetUpSoftwares\XilinxProjects\Assignments-1\Demultiplexer.vhd" Line 53: Cannot read from 'out' object i5 ; use 'buffer' or 'inout'
ERROR:HDLCompiler:1731 - "H:\SetUpSoftwares\XilinxProjects\Assignments-1\Demultiplexer.vhd" Line 53: found '0' definitions of operator "<=", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "<="
ERROR:HDLCompiler:288 - "H:\SetUpSoftwares\XilinxProjects\Assignments-1\Demultiplexer.vhd" Line 54: Cannot read from 'out' object i6 ; use 'buffer' or 'inout'
ERROR:HDLCompiler:1731 - "H:\SetUpSoftwares\XilinxProjects\Assignments-1\Demultiplexer.vhd" Line 54: found '0' definitions of operator "<=", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "<="
ERROR:HDLCompiler:288 - "H:\SetUpSoftwares\XilinxProjects\Assignments-1\Demultiplexer.vhd" Line 55: Cannot read from 'out' object i7 ; use 'buffer' or 'inout'
ERROR:HDLCompiler:1731 - "H:\SetUpSoftwares\XilinxProjects\Assignments-1\Demultiplexer.vhd" Line 55: found '0' definitions of operator "<=", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "<="
ERROR:HDLCompiler:854 - "H:\SetUpSoftwares\XilinxProjects\Assignments-1\Demultiplexer.vhd" Line 45: Unit <behavioral> ignored due to previous   errors.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your conditional assignments wrong. The syntax is

```
i0 <= a when s = "000" else other_value;  -- whatever your code is supposed to do
i1 <= a when s = "001" else other_value;
...
```

The (a little misleading) error message is caused by the i1 assignment in the next line:

```
i0 <= a when s = "000" else i1 ...
```

This is as the code was understood (until it completely bailed out) and this would mean you are trying to read from an `out` signal which is not supported until VHDL 2008.

Comment: i have edited my architecture to be

    I0 <= A WHEN S = "000" ELSE 'Z';    and so on.

and it works . . thanks a lot.